# partitions not recognized after formatting one volume in a 2TB WD drive

Tags: partitioning, format, gpt, fat32, multi-volume

I have a 2TB disk (WD20EZRX) which had 10 partitions (around 200GB each).

One of the partitions was FAT32 and I was trying to copy a file into it which was 165GB so I was getting a message saying the filesystem could not handle such large file so I formatted that particular Volume to NTFS.

After doing so I rebooted and I lost access to my drive. It now shows as "GPT" in Disk Management and I don't see any of the 10 volumes that I had in it.

All I did was format the volume as NTFS and I was able to do stuff with the disk afterwards, it became unusable after reboot.

I tried with a partition program to find out what was wrong but I only see one big 2TB partition as GPT and I can't create / delete or do anything with my drive.

I don't want to format the whole drive because I have lot of data in it that I can't loose.

I suspect my other volumes were FAT32 as well and maybe I messed up by formatting one volume as NTFS? Any ideas what I can do to recover or at least see the volumes I had? I'm downloading a linux live CD to see if I can access the data by booting into a linux system but not sure.

[image]

Comment: it is possible that  partition is Unallocated space , please post disk management screen shot

Comment: Hi, I attached the disk management screenshot.

Comment: please check the video to fix http://bit.ly/2aqxbcK

Comment: did  you solve it ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to convert to MBR succesfully. It seems the partition was corrupted somehow so all data was lost anyways.